# Is there a way to change the behavior of pattern matching the entire input?

Tags: regex, html, forms, input

In my testing, it appears that using the `pattern` attribute in a `form` `input` requires matching the whole text value; *i.e.* the browser is basically adding `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the `pattern` RegEx string, respectively. Is there any way to "turn this off" so I don't have to add `.*` to the beginning and end of each `pattern` string that I don't want matched to the entire input string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked the standard specification there was not, and I would recommend using the `.*` even if there was such a feature as the intent is immediately clear.

Comment: You sound confident so I will assume you are correct. :) But seriously I was expecting that to be the case - would have been pleasantly surprised if it wasn't.